# How to catch any type of application exit?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application.
I have implemented the following function, but no one catches all type of application exits.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {}

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {}

    private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {}

    private void Application_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingCancelEventArgs e)
    {}
}
```

- **Is there a generic way to handle application exit?**

For example none of above methods fires when application is forced closed (killed).
Each time application closes, I need to unlock some objects in database that is locked by user during application run.

Comment: The first 2 should be linked (the same). And the 3rd is an error exit,

Comment: @Henk Exakt, I need a generic one.

Comment: @Henk Not that type of generic, I mean a way to catch all type of exists.

Comment: You have a way to catch (all catchable) exits. Just over 2 or 3 methods, that can't be a real problem.

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` is useful for any exception on a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** catch *all* types of exists unless you are running an observer, separate from your application being surveyed (the "target" application).

The reason being you cannot internally catch application crashes (duh), forced process termination (both internal and external) or anything to that effect.

What you have done is perfectly good.

If you do wish to implement a separate observer application, you can use the .NET `Process.Exited` event, which is fired whenever a process exists for any reason, including application crashes.

Also, as @Christian has pointed out, you *should not* try to have a catch-all solution, especially when dealing with critical application crashes (this point is subjective). " When you somehow manage [to recover from an unhandled application error], you're usually doing something wrong or at least may get inaccurate results (e.g. when trying to P/Invoke a minidump creation from your own process)."

Comment: I have implemented Process.GetCurrentProcess().Exited but it didn't fire. I implemented it in constructor for public partial class App : Application.

Comment: +1: I'd even extend it to "You *cannot* and *should not*". Because even when you somehow manage, you're usually doing something wrong or at least may get inaccurate results (e.g. when trying to P/Invoke a minidump creation from your own process).

Comment: @Amir Rezaei: How should it? When the *current* process has exited, it cannot report that to itself.

Comment: @Christian: You raise a very good point ! I'll fix up my response with your additional comments.

Comment: @Christian.K Yes, but shouldn't AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit fire?

Comment: @Amir: If an application *crashes*, then it has abnormally and prematurely exited. Code execution immediately halts and the process exits (forcefully). No more code, including any exit handlers within the *same process space*, will be executed. If you have an external observer running in another separate process, then that process will be notified of the exit and you can handle it there.

Comment: @Amir Rezaei: Yes, but not on all circumstances. I.e. when the CLR crashes, or when someone calls `Environment.FailFast()` or even P/Invoke `TerminateProcess()`, it probably won't.

Comment: @freedompeace What I should do or not, or what is the best ideal way to do thing is not the reality for most of us. I'm sitting on a system with a very bad exception handling. So my job is to free resources locked in database when application some how crashes. There is no time to refactor the application. So here I'm and I have to "fix" the problem. Thanks anyway for your recommendations!

Comment: @Amir, I understand. However, there are limitations on things we can and cannot do. The best you can do here is a global catch-all for .NET exceptions. Any process-level crashes cannot be caught by a single application, and so you'll have to forgo those. These kinds of crashes will be especially prevalent if you are using native/unmanaged libraries in your software.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a handler to the [AppDomain.ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) event; as far as I can tell, it's the most reliable way to tell when your application is exiting.

This won't be available if you move your app to Silverlight, but as long as you stay within WPF (or any other "full-sized" .NET framework app) this should do the trick.

Comment: It didn't fire when I closed application by Visual Studio stop button.